# Using external modules in a Pycharm project

Tags: python, module, pycharm

I am new to Pycharm and need some help. I am working on a project that makes use of a large library of modules (specifically, Schrodinger; which allows for a lot of cool chemistry programs). Schrodinger requires the use of Python 2.7, if that makes any difference.

There are too many modules to install to the project directory. When I move the project directory to the location of the modules, my script becomes stuck on 'initializing'. I have attempted to import it as a package to no avail.

I have also tried to use the sys.path command, however a lot of the modules make use of other modules as well. So I that has become a pain very quickly.

How can I use these modules within Pycharm? And if there is no easy way, do you have a recommendation for an IDE that does have this feature?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pycharm doesn't identifies user defined modules which are not imported to Pycharm.

I usually mask the module as a `Sources Root` see the picture for more details. if the modules are in same project.

Alternative way:  In your case import the external modules using `File -> Open` modules with `open -> open in current window -> add to currently opened project` this looks like two different projects. Now you can mark `Sources Root` for the complete module `(i.e. learning)` which you have imported.

```
import stackoverflow
```

Now pycharm can identifies the user defined modules.

[image]